# Unable to determine location of a particular geometry and Method to retrieve geometry using its location and sizes

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using HelixToolkit and programming using C#.

I wrote the following code in order to create a cube:

```
 var meshBuilder3 = new MeshBuilder(false, false);
 meshBuilder3.AddBox(new Point3D(1, 9, 15), 2, 2, 2);
 var mesh1000 = meshBuilder3.ToMesh(true);
 Color halfTransparent = Color.FromArgb(127, Colors.Black.R, Colors.Black.G, Colors.Black.B);
 var TranspMaterial = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(halfTransparent);
 modelGroup.Children.Add(new GeometryModel3D { Geometry = mesh1000, Material = TranspMaterial });
```

Now, I wrote few more lines in order to retrieve the Geometrical object.

```
Model3DCollection children  = modelGroup.Children;
Model3D model = children[0];
GeometryModel3D geom3D = (GeometryModel3D)model;
Geometry3D geo3D = geom3D.Geometry;
Rect3D rec3D = geo3D.Bounds;
Point3D x = rec3D.Location;
```

When I pointed my cursor on `Rect3D` object and tried to look at the location and `X,Y,Z` size values, it was displaying location as `{0,8,5}` and `X,Y,Z` as `13,5,5` respectively.

But my cube size is `2` and location is `{1,9,15}`. I don't understand why its printing some wrong value.

Also I went through all the methods available, but I could not find any method which retrieves `GeometryModel3D` object if we pass location and center values. If I have a location of my cube and also its size, can I retrieve `Geometry3D` object. Because if I try to retrieve the children, loop the whole children and then if I try to verify the locations of each children with the desired one, it would be really a huge programme and requires more computational time.

I want something like this:

```
GeometryModel3D geom3D = children.find(Point3D Location,double sizeX,double sizeY,double sizeZ);
```

I would be really glad,if someone can answer these two questions.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure you still have the cube object after your `ToMesh` call? This name suggests that it turns your geometry into mesh polygons / triangles.

Comment: But I dont have any cube Object above, because,when return type of the function AddBox is void. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I've just pulled down the toolkit. Unfortunately your code doesn't compile, so I can't even reproduce this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've able to create roughly duplicate your code using `v1.0.0` [release](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/releases/tag/v1.0.0) of the toolkit by the following code.

```
var modelGroup = new GroupModel3D();

var meshBuilder3 = new MeshBuilder(false, false);
meshBuilder3.AddBox(new Vector3(1, 9, 15), 2, 2, 2);
var mesh1000 = meshBuilder3.ToMesh();

var geomdeModel3D = new MeshGeometryModel3D {Geometry = mesh1000};
modelGroup.Children.Add(geomdeModel3D);

var children = modelGroup.Children;
var model = children[0];
GeometryModel3D geom3D = (GeometryModel3D)model;


Geometry3D geo3D = geom3D.Geometry;
var bound = geo3D.Bound;
Console.WriteLine(bound); // <--- Minimum:X:0 Y:8 Z:14 Maximum:X:2 Y:10 Z:16
```

The bound retrieved here is actually correct.

---

Regarding your second part of the question. What you requested is not as simple as you thought. Since this toolkit seems like a mesh manipulation tool, `AddBox` doesn't actually created a (traditionally speaking) box, i.e. an object with it's 6 vertices, but generated several mesh polygons / triangles under the hood. This means that although the geometry still has a physical center and looks like a 'box', doing what you asked is quite tricky (unless with a lot of assumptions).

For example, you could actually add cylinder or tube in the same model group alongside the box. Then your `children.find` won't be able to know whether each children is a box (without sophisticated checks).

- If you know you will always only have boxes inside your model group, then you can use the `Bound` property's  `Minimum` and `Maximum` to do the check, by iterating `Children`
- If you purely want some structure to store your collection of boxes, you can just implement your own box collection, perhaps with the help of algorithm like KD-Tree to perform a quicker run-time search.

Comment: Thanks mate! that really helped!